# Can Swift cast a UInt to an Enum with "as"?

Tags: swift

I'm aware of creating an `Enum` from a `UInt` using `rawValue:`.  However, can Swift cast a `UInt` to an `Enum` using `as`?  Here's a screenshot from the WWDC 2016 talk [Delivering an Exceptional Audio Experience](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/507/):

[image: WWDC sample code casting to Enum]

As you can see, the code retrieves a numeric value from the dictionary and casts it to an `Enum` using `as!`.

I haven't been able to do this in my code.  Is it valid Swift?

Comment: Ye it is valid Swift. I have used it many times mostly when it suggested to do it but do not remember exact example.

Comment: I was not able to make it work in my version of Xcode 8 and I have tried a direct cast, a cast through `AnyObject` and a cast through `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to reproduce the code with the same enum and with my own enums and the cast always crashes as it should, in my opinion, e.g.:

```
let x: AVAudioSessionInterruptionType = .began
let dictionary: NSDictionary = [AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey: x.rawValue as NSNumber]

// crash
let value = dictionary[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as! AVAudioSessionInterruptionType
```

I went through the Swift evolution list and I haven't found a change that could cause this to work. To be honest, not all code snippets shown in WWDC are working.

Comment: (I'm not on Mac, so can't test myself) can you use `x` (of `AVAudioSessionInterruptionType` type) directly as value in an `NSDictionary` that is type specified as `NSObject: AnyObject`? (using `AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey` as key)

Comment: @dfri No because an enum is a value type and `AnyObject` represents classes.